# Simular click com jQuery depois que inserir link via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho que abrir uma outra aba com um link que é retornavel para do PHP para jQuery. Eu usei `window.open` mas ele pede para liberar o `popup` e o cliente não gosto nada disso. Então pensei em fazer, quando o jQuery receber o link, ele altera um `<a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank"></a>` para `<a href="http://www.LinkQueRetornou.com.br" target="_blank"></a>` e executa uma função para simular um click para abrir em outra aba. O problema é que fiz o código abaixo e não está funcionando, pois ele não abre a página em outra aba, agora não sei se é porque o link foi adicionado depois em uma ação jQuery (DOM).

**HTML + jQuery**

```
<button class="button" type="button" id="teste">Click</button>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="linkredirect" target="_blank"></a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#teste").click(function(){

            $("a#linkredirect").prop('href', 'http://www.google.com.br');
            $("a#linkredirect").trigger("click");
        })
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Como você tava usando com `window.open`? Aqui pra mim (no Chrome) seu código abriu normal em outra aba com `window.open` e `_blank`. Veja no [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/om0js91z/).

Comment: Sim, no meu também funcionou. Mas no do cliente pediu pra permitir popup. Acho que o dele era Safari

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar a função `$(seletor).trigger("click");` 
use `$(seletor)[0].click();`.

**Bom, mas porque?**

Segundo a resposta do @The Alpha nesta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486630/jquery-trigger-click-vs-click), o que acontece é que no caso da função `trigger()` a execução não irá disparar uma evento de click propriamente dito e sim executar um manipulador de evento, se declarado, como por exemplo:

```
$(selector).click(function() {
    // some code...
});
```

**Tá, mas porque utilizar o `[0]` antes do `.click();` ?**

Se faz necessário o uso do 0 entre colchetes, por que a função `click()` é nativa do javascript, sendo assim não pertence a um objeto jQuery. Se não utilizar `[0]` para pegar somente o elemento HTML a função `click()` terá a mesma funcionalidade da `trigger()`.

Dessa maneira seu código funcionará.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#teste").click(function(){
        $("a#linkredirect").prop('href', 'http://www.google.com.br');
        $("a#linkredirect")[0].click();
    });
});
```

> Veja funcionando também no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g7ktj1bs/)

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou aqui seu código!!

Comment: @AlissonAcioli irei adicionar a resposta o porque disto.

Comment: Tudo bem ;).. Muito obrigado mesmo!